# Efficient way to store a PySpark Object

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark

I am using the syntax below to query a large database using `PySpark`:

```
df = spark.sql("""
SELECT id, start_time, end_time, value
FROM df_qck_dbase
""")
```

and then convert the object to `Pandas` data frame using the syntax:

```
data = df.toPandas()
```

However, the conversion to Pandas takes hours and in some cases never completes. I have also tried saving it as csv and the same issue occurs.

I am wondering whether there are alternative work arounds in saving the results and loading them in Pandas.

P.S: The SQL seems not to have a problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Spark is a parallel computation system. If you convert a pyspark dataset into a Pandas dataframe, you are opting out of the parallel computation. That's inherently going to be slow. For the specific problem you're having, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57311192/how-to-save-csv-files-faster-from-pyspark-dataframe

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to use: `data = df.to_pandas_on_spark()`? This lets you treat spark much like pandas. For pure pandas though... If the dataframe is large enough, it's *never* going to work, no matter how you save/load it.

Comment: If you absolutely need to save a local copy, I'd recommend saving it as a `parquet`